# Split and capture hyphenated string

Tags: regex, prometheus

Our machine names are structured like -- e.g. "S01-MAIL-M01". I want to be able to catch "S01", "MAIL", "M01" as $1, $2, $3 but I cannot get a regex to work, I really am not experienced with them.

I was testing things like `/(.*)\-+/` but this would capture "S01-MAIL" when I test on https://regex101.com/

I am doing this within a Prometheus configuration script, so obvious programming tools like `Split` are not available, only regex.

Comment: If supported, you can use 3 capture groups `^(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)$` or `^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$` https://regex101.com/r/UU3eLk/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PHlcJ5/1

Comment: can this be generalised to N groups rather than hard-coded for 3?

Comment: I think prometheus uses the re2 engine for regex. If you want to access the separate groups by number, you would have to specify all 3 of them.

Comment: How many groups are you looking at maximum? You can make optional capture groups if you want like [`^(\w+)(?:-(\w+))?(?:-(\w+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/yq8XRF/1) and expand on it if need be.

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird/JvdV it seems it would be easier to live around this limitation than try and get overly complicated

Comment: You might want to consider rephrasing your question, as it is not about a general regex issue, but splitting up a single label value into three

Answer (score 1):

for my example I assume the machine name is in the label `instance` and it shall be splitted into `datacenter`, `service` and `node_number`

you need three relabel rules:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: instance
    target_label: datacenter
    regex: ^(\w+)-\w+-\w+$
  - source_labels: instance
    target_label: service
    regex: ^\w+-(\w+)-\w+$
  - source_labels: instance
    target_label: node_number
    regex: ^\w+-\w+-(\w+)$
```

Each rule extracts one element and puts it into a seperate label.

Comment: Thanks for the prometheus-specific answer. Shouldn't you use `$1` over `$` or is this an allowed short-hand?

Comment: In the beginning I had in one rule `replacement: $1`, I assume you refer that. Since that is the default, you dont need to configure it, so I removed it.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering why your regex ends with `$`

Comment: That matches if input ends at thaat position. if it would be left out it would match to an input string like "S01-MAIL-M01 something else"

Answer (score 0):

The following regex separate to 3 capture groups
/([A-Z0-9]+)/gm

https://regex101.com/r/otfJXW/1